# How to download/read only the first 80KB of a file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, download, greasemonkey

I am making a Greasemonkey script for a website that has many flash files. I'd like to make a hash of the flash, the problem is that the flash files are up to 10 megabytes.

This is slow; I'd like to be able to only grab the first 80KB to hash. The end result would be an easy way to blacklist certain flash files containing unwanted content. 
How does my script grab only the first 80 KB (or so) of a file?

Comment: how do you plan on blacklisting files if you only ready 80k of the file?

Comment: @mkoryak Well, perhaps I should use a bit more then the first 80KB but I am only looking for unique within a reasonable ballpark. I haven't tested it myself but I suspect that due to the nature of the compiled flash it will be reasonable for what I need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Send [the `range` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2) in your AJAX request.

For example:

```
$.ajax ( {
    url:        'http://TARGET_SERVER.COM/TARGET_PATH/TARGET_FILE.FLV',
    headers:    { Range: "bytes=0-80000" },
    success:    function (Resp) {
                    console.log(Resp);
                }
} );
```

(For files that are on the same-domain as the target page.)

---

For cross-domain files use [GM_xmlhttpRequest()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest):

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:     "GET",
    url:        'http://TARGET_SERVER.COM/TARGET_PATH/TARGET_FILE.FLV',
    headers:    { Range: "bytes=0-80000" },
    onload:     function (Resp) {
                    console.log(Resp.responseText);
                }
} );
```

Comment: **+1** for two methods I have not used myself, but this will come in handy. Thanks!